# Does AHEasing run in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I'm trying to use [AHEasing](https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing) in my Swift project.  I've installed it via cocoapods and included this line in my bridging header:

```
#import <AHEasing/CAKeyframeAnimation+AHEasing.h>
```

I am able to access the function in CAKeyframeAnimation+AHEasing.h just fine, but when I try

```
var alphaAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation.animationWithKeyPath("alpha", function: QuadraticEaseInOut, fromValue: 1.0, toValue: 0.0)
```

I get the error

```
Cannot invoke 'animationWithKeyPath' with an argument list of type '(String, function: (Double) -> Double, fromValue: Double, toValue: Double)'
```

After a little digging, I confirmed that QuadraticEaseInOut is indeed being converted to a (Double) -> Double closure, while the type for that parameter, AHEasingFunction, is being converted into a CFunctionPointer<((Double) -> Double)>.

Is there a way to convert between these 2 types?  Has anyone successfully used AHEasing in Swift?  Is there another work around that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard reports from some people that this is a Swift 1.2 issue, that is no longer a problem in Swift 2.

Either way, I just worked around the problem by implementing the functionality that I needed from AHEasing entirely in Swift.